# How do you go from a discrete sum of waves $u(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e^{ikx}$ to a continuous integral $u(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} A(k) e^{ikx} dk$

Tags: fourier-series, periodic-functions

A periodic function can be described by a sum of monochromatic waves as follows:

$$ u(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j e^{ik_jx} $$
However I am studying wave packets, and I understand that these have a 'continuous' range of wave numbers $k$. I also see that an integral is needed, but what is the derivation from the above sum to the next integral?

$$
u(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} A(k) e^{ikx} dk
$$

I tried with riemann sums but I could not make it work. Also the sum does not have a '$\Delta k$'-like term.

Comment: Sums arise from the Fourier Theory of $S^1$, while integrals arise from the Fourier Theory of $\mathbb R$. Both are special cases of Pontrayagin Duality.

Comment: Is $i=\sqrt{-1}$?  If so, do not do summation from $i=1$ to $n$.  My guess at what you intend.  The first one is (roughly) "Fourier series" and the second one is "Fourier transform".  Look for these two terms.

Comment: Thank you I have editted that. I know it is connected to Fourier series etc, but there is so much information on this that I cannot find the trees in the forest. Also very commonly it is just handwavingly (or not at all) explained.

Answer (score 1):

**Preliminary note :** you should write $k_i$ instead of $k$ in the sum, otherwise your signal contains a unique frequency.

---

**Answer.**
The quickest way to go from discrete to continuous frequency spectrum (i.e. from series to integral representations), and *vice versa*, is taking $A(k) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^na_i\delta(k-k_i)$ as a truncated Dirac comb.

Like that, the integral behaves / is recasted as a discrete sum, and *vice versa*. In measure theory, we would say that a counting measure is used for the integral; measure theory has been precisely developped to treat sums and integrals together, so that discrete and continuous quantities can be mixed up and described in the same way.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that mistake, I have editted the question. I don't understand your sum. Are you summing from the wavenumber $k=1$ to $n$?

Comment: @bananenheld Sorry, it was a mistake of mine, it is now edited.